# Bursty packet traffic in Java

Tags: java, network-programming, poisson

I have a requirement to simulate a network traffic which is Poisson and Bursty (Long or Heavy Tailed) inter arrival times. I could do the Poisson part as

```
delay = - log(1 - rand.nextDouble()) * delay;
```

However, I am stuck with simulating the Bursty traffic simulation. Could someone hint/point me to the right web resource or code to achieve this? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and safest thing might be to download a library that supports various types of long-tailed distributions, such as a Pareto distribution, and call that API's `nextRandom` method (or the equivalent).

Comment: [a.] Thanks a zillion!! :) I am going with this library (http://www.jsc.nildram.co.uk/downloads/download.html). Any better ones please let me know... 

[b.] But other wise can we implement it ourselves using a fun similar to "public static double pareto(double alpha)" in this link (http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdRandom.java.html)??